# how to resolve foreign key relations to user model in django

Tags: python, django

Consider the django auth User model inherited to create the users.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Domain(models.Model):
  customer = models.ForeignKey(User)

class EmailAccount(models.Model):
  domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)
```

I wish to create more than 1 user for the given UserProfile instance(User profile is a customer that should be stored only once); if another user is created, he will be able to manage the particular domain only and hence the email accounts created on that domain. He should not be able to access any email accounts created on any other domain for the same user once he logs in. I wish to use the django admin to do the same.

Comment: I think you can create more than one user in Userprofile and your model is correct. Have you test that one?

Comment: If you wish to create more than one user for a give UserProfile instance, you should change the field type from `models.OneToOneField(User)` to `models.ForeignKey(User)`.

Comment: @Cole by doing so we will have for the same user, multiple userprofiles exactly reverse of what I want! Please note I want to use User inheritance to create multiple users for the same userprofile.

Comment: @princess after testing only I have raised the question on stack

Answer (score 0):

`Many-to-many` relationships allow many on either side.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    Users = models.ManyToMany(User)

>>> u1 = User(id=1)
>>> u2 = User(id=2)
>>> user_profile = UserProfile()
>>> user_profile.save()
>>> user_profile.users.all()
[]
>>> user_profile.users.add(u1.id, u2.id)
>>> user_profile.save()
>>> user_profile.users.all()
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me Cole. Anyways thanx for the efforts. Cheers

Comment: UserProfile is an extension of the django.auth User model. I am trying to inherit the user as the customer. I want to  add a domain admin (another user) to the customer. UserProfile organization attribute is unique in the system. I don't wish to add another duplicate profile object for the  domain admin of a customer.